# Voltage Regulator Issue (TI TLV70012)

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm using [this 1.2 V voltage regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv70025.pdf) and having some serious problems.

Currently have +5 V going to EN and IN pins and GND is connected to GND, seeing ~1.6 V on OUT pin when connecting it to GND through 8k resistor.

I have been trying to figure out why the regulator is not outputting 1.2 V for days now and I am completely stumped.

Any ideas?

Comment: A schematic of your circuit and a photo of how you built it might both help us see some reason your circuit isn't behaving the way you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These devices need input and output capacitors to keep them stable. Take a look at the datasheet:

[image: datasheet excerpt]

Without local caps (as close as possible to the pins) these things can and will oscillate, which unless you're looking with a scope can appear as incorrect DC voltage levels.

Add caps and try again. If you're still not having any luck post some scope shots of the input and output voltages.

Comment: looks like it was an oscillatory problem. Output cap cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an output capacitor?? The datasheet states "Furthermore, these devices are stable with an effective output capacitance of only 0.1 μF"
I think that might be your issue